# ASHX simultaneous call session variables wrong

Tags: asp.net, session-variables, ashx

I am working on a website that may have an issue.

if two users hit the ashx page at the same time, it looks like the seconds users session variables are placed in the first users session, and the second user ends up just erroring out.

Does this even sound possible? I would think an ashx can handle multiple simultaneous hits.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you implementing IReadOnlySessionState or IRequiresSessionState?

Comment: yes, we are using IRequiresSessionState.

Comment: My second thought is that they are not easy to debug. How do you recognize this behaviour? Whats your IsReusable value?

Comment: What ever is default (i haven't set IsResuable anywhere). I found the error after looking at logs. Basically, the ashx page does an sql query, and my only thought is that when the second person (at the exact same time) hit the ashx, the queries got mixed up (the first persons query result was thrown away and the second persons query was given to the first person). That is my only plausible explanation, and I am not sure it is even plausible...

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It is company code, and their are strict policies about that.

Comment: By themselves, the handlers can handle session variables. It would be interesting to see how you access the session and how the SQL is being executed/called/handled...

Comment: A business object (.cs) is the go between for the ashx and the xsd data set, if that helps at all.

Comment: Sorry, without seeing what is being done and how it is handled, I can only guess.